# Accessing Public data via the YouTube data API without Authentication.

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to make requests to the [Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/), but I do not need to access any user information. I just want to browse through the public videos and display videos based on search terms.

Am I able to do this without authorization?

Comment: @DalmTo is correct. Here's just additional working samples that you can run on your localhost immediately: The [working demo youtube project](https://github.com/FriesFlorian/viralvideos) doing that. The accompanying youtube tutorial is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vH2eZAM30s).

Answer (score 5):

A lot of the methods in the YouTube API access public data.   As you stated public data is data not owned by a user.   To access public data you do not need to be authenticated but you must still register your application with Google.

You need to go to [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) create a project make sure to enable the YouTube Data API and request an API Key.

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=25&q=surfing&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

You can then just add `key={YOUR_API_KEY}` to any of the public methods.

You can test it [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=25&q=surfing&_h=1&) make sure to click the link   **Execute without OAuth** and not the blue button.